Conexión de App vía Bluetooth con otros dispositivos en Kotlin
Soy bastante nuevo en Kotlin y estoy creando una App con Android Studio que me permita conectarme a un ESP32 para configurarlo vía Bluetooth. He intentado seguir los pasos de Android developer sobre el Bluetooth, pero hay pasos que se me escapan de mis conocimientos. Seguí un tutorial de una app en YouTube que en teoría me permitía activar o desactivar el Bluetooth, buscar dispositivos cercanos y mostrarlos en un spinner, conectarme a uno de ellos y con diferentes botones mandar datos para activar o desactivar salidas.
El caso es que en el video funciona y a mí se me cierra la App cuando interactúo con el botón de activar o desactivar Bluetooth. También se me cierra cuando pulso el botón de buscar dispositivos Bluetooth y por lo tanto no me salen en la lista desplegable.
Los permisos en el Android Manifest son los siguientes:
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"
    android:maxSdkVersion="30"/>
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"
    android:maxSdkVersion="30"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADVERTISE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>

Y el código de la aplicación es el siguiente:
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.enableEdgeToEdge
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.core.view.ViewCompat
import androidx.core.view.WindowInsetsCompat
import android.Manifest
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothManager
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.content.pm.PackageManager
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.*
import java.io.IOException
import java.util.*
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat
import androidx.activity.result.contract.ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult

const val REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 1

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    //BluetoothAdapter
    lateinit var mBtAdapter: BluetoothAdapter
    var mAddressDevices: ArrayAdapter<String>? = null
    var mNameDevices: ArrayAdapter<String>? = null

    companion object {
        var m_myUUID: UUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB")
        var m_bluetoothShocket: BluetoothSocket? = null
        var m_isConnected: Boolean = false
        lateinit var m_address: String
    }
    
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        mAddressDevices = ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1)
        mNameDevices = ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1)

        val idBtnOnBt = findViewById<Button>(R.id.idBtnOnBt)
        val idBtnOffBt = findViewById<Button>(R.id.idBtnOffBt)
        val idBtnDispBt = findViewById<Button>(R.id.idBtnDispBt)
        val idBtnEnviar = findViewById<Button>(R.id.idBtnEnviar)
        val idBtnConnect = findViewById<Button>(R.id.idBtnConnect)
        val idBtnLuz_1on = findViewById<Button>(R.id.idBtnLuz_1on)
        val idBtnLuz_1off = findViewById<Button>(R.id.idBtnLuz_1off)
        val idBtnLuz_2on = findViewById<Button>(R.id.idBtnLuz_2on)
        val idBtnLuz_2off = findViewById<Button>(R.id.idBtnLuz_2off)
        val idTextOut = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.idTextOut)
        val idSpinDisp = findViewById<Spinner>(R.id.idSpinDisp)

        val someActivityResultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(StartActivityForResult()){
            result ->
            if(result.resultCode == REQUEST_ENABLE_BT){
                Log.i("MainActivity","ACTIVIDAD REGISTRADA")
            }
        }

        // Inicializacion del bluetoothAdapter

        mBtAdapter = (getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE) as BluetoothManager).adapter

        // Comprobar si esta encendido o apagado

        if(mBtAdapter==null){
            Toast.makeText(this,"Bluetooth NO disponible!!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(this,"Bluetooth DISPONIBLE!!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

        }
        
        idBtnOnBt.setOnClickListener {
            if(mBtAdapter.isEnabled){// ACTIVAR BLUETOOTH
                // Si ya esta activado
                Toast.makeText(this,"El Bluetooth ya esta activado",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }else{
                //Encender bluetooth
                val enableBtIntent = Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE)
                if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                        this,
                        Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT
                    ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                {
                    Log.i("MainActivity","ActivityCompact#RequestPermissions")
                }
                someActivityResultLauncher.launch(enableBtIntent)
            }
        }
        
        idBtnOffBt.setOnClickListener {// DESACTIVAR BLUETOOTH
            if(!mBtAdapter.isEnabled){
                //Si ya esta desactivado
                Toast.makeText(this,"El Bluetooth ya se encuentra  desactivado",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }else{
                //Desactivar el Bluetooth
                mBtAdapter.disable()
                Toast.makeText(this,"Se ha desactivado el Bluetooth",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }

        idBtnDispBt.setOnClickListener {// EMPAREJAR DISPOSITIVOS
        // Boton emparejar dispositivos
            if(mBtAdapter.isEnabled){
                val pairDevices: Set<BluetoothDevice>? = mBtAdapter?.bondedDevices
                mAddressDevices!!.clear()
                mNameDevices!!.clear()

                pairDevices?.forEach{
                    device ->
                    val deviceName = device.name
                    val deviceHardwareAddress = device.address //MAC ADDRESS
                    mAddressDevices!!.add(deviceHardwareAddress)
                    // En este punto se guardan los nombres a mostrarse en el combo box
                    mNameDevices!!.add(deviceName)
                }
                // Actualizo los dispositivos
                idSpinDisp.setAdapter(mNameDevices)
            }else{
                val noDevices = "Ningun dispositivo emparejado"
                mAddressDevices!!.add(noDevices)
                mNameDevices!!.add(noDevices)
                Toast.makeText(this,"Primero vincule un dispositivo Bluetooth",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }
        idBtnConnect.setOnClickListener {
            try{
                if(m_bluetoothShocket == null || !m_isConnected){
                    val intValSpin = idSpinDisp.selectedItemPosition
                    m_address = mAddressDevices!!.getItem(intValSpin).toString()
                    Toast.makeText(this, m_address,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    // Cancel discovery because it otherwise slows down the connection
                    mBtAdapter?.cancelDiscovery()
                    val device: BluetoothDevice = mBtAdapter.getRemoteDevice(m_address)
                    m_bluetoothShocket=device.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(m_myUUID)
                    m_bluetoothShocket!!.connect()
                }
                Toast.makeText(this,"Conexion exitosa",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                Log.i("MainAcivity","Conexion exitosa")
            }catch(e:IOException){
                //ConnectSuccess = false
                e.printStackTrace()
                Toast.makeText(this,"Error de conexion",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                Log.i("MainActivity","Error de conexion")
            }
        }

        idBtnLuz_1on.setOnClickListener { // AQUI SE ENVIAN LOS DATOS AL DISPOSITIVO BLUETOOTH
            sendCommand("A")
        }
        idBtnLuz_1off.setOnClickListener {
            sendCommand("B")
        }
        idBtnLuz_2on.setOnClickListener {
            sendCommand("C")
        }
        idBtnLuz_2off.setOnClickListener {
            sendCommand("D")
        }

        idBtnEnviar.setOnClickListener { // AQUI SE ENVIA EL TEXTO INGRESADO EN EL EDITTEXT

            if(idTextOut.text.toString().isEmpty()){
                Toast.makeText(this,"Los datos a enviar no pueden estar vacios", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }else{
                var mensaje_out: String = idTextOut.text.toString()
                sendCommand(mensaje_out)
            }
        }
    }

    private fun sendCommand(input: String){
        if(m_bluetoothShocket != null){
            try {
                m_bluetoothShocket!!.outputStream.write(input.toByteArray())
            }catch (e: IOException){
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
        }
    }
}

No se de donde me viene el problema, pero quería usar este ejemplo como prueba para el código de mi App. Espero que podáis echarme una mano con él.

ESP32 tiene TCP/IP y WiFi, que son mejores alternativas de conexión que BT.

Como ya he comentado soy nuevo en la programación y agradezco tus ideas. Las consideraré para el tema de mi app. Sin embargo, y aunque no sea la mejor opción, me gustaría saber donde falla el código. Saludos.

Ya trabaje con ESP8266 y BT. Funcionaba a veces. A veces no pareaba, no conectaba, se colgaba, etc. De ahí en adelante, sólo TCP/IP.

Tendrias algún ejemplo al que echarle un vistazo??

Podrías mostrar el error? Puedes obtenerlo con logcat
